# How to reduce font size in equation for text

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, scaling

I have a slide in my beamer presentation that looks like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$$ y= 1/x \qquad \scriptscriptstyle {\mbox{For}~ x>0} $$
$$ y= 1/x \qquad \scriptscriptstyle {\mbox{For}}~ x>0 $$
$$ y= 1/x \qquad \mbox{For}~ \scriptscriptstyle {x>0} $$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To save space, I want to reduce the size of $\mbox{For}~ x>0$ with \scriptscriptstyle but all the three ways of using this command give me the same result only $x>0$ is re-sized. Is the command \mbox the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `\mbox` content is not influenced by the layout you define outside. To achieve what you are looking for you can use `\text` instead of `\mbox`.
Furthermore, do not use `$$...$$`, but `\[...\]` or `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to). And I think the space after the protected space `~` should not be there.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
    y= 1/x \qquad \scriptscriptstyle {\text{For}~x>0}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

P.S. The protected space ~ is not anymore required when we replace \mbox by \text.

Answer (score 4):

The `\mbox` macro, as you've discovered, isn't sufficiently aware of the surrounding font size. I suggest you (a) use `\text` (rather than `\mbox`) to encase both the word "for" and the formula $x>0$ and (b) not use the math-mode `\scriptscriptstyle` directive but the text-mode directive `\tiny` as the first instruction in the argument of `\text`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
    y= 1/x \qquad \text{\tiny for $x>0$}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```